# Select columns with count of related items from tables in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table structure where Albums are arranges as per categories so we have Categories as top level, Albums at second level and Photos and third level.

I need to show AlbumCategories details with Name & count of albums under this categories. How can I query this if I want the following result based on dummy data below

```
Sports(2)
Education(3)


TABLE AlbumCategories
ACID    Name
1       Sports
2       Education


TABLE albums
AID     ACID    Name
1       1       Footbal season 2015
2       1       Footbal season 2016
3       2       Album one
4       2       Album Two
5       3       Album Three


TABLE albumsPhotos
PID     AID Image
```

Comment: `Select .. count .. table .. join table .. group by`. Shouldn't the `education` count be `2`

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: why is there a (3) for Education in your example ?

Comment: Not sure how this question is getting upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` is all that is required:

```
SELECT AC.ACID
     , MAX(AC.Name) as Name
     , COUNT(*) as Frequency FROM Album A
       INNER JOIN AlbumCategories AC ON A.ACID = AC.ACID
       GROUP BY AC.ACID
```

To get all Categories regardless of whether there are any Albums use this query:

```
 SELECT AC.ACID
     , MAX(AC.Name) as Name
     , COUNT(*) as Frequency FROM AlbumCategories AC
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Album A ON A.ACID = AC.ACID
       GROUP BY AC.ACID
```

Comment: shouldn't `AlbumCategories` be in place of `Sport` in your query as there is no sports table

Comment: Struggling with query to get all records with this coury i only get records which have Albums but not all the categories

Comment: @Learning, have updated with an alternative that handles that.